# Query identical element name with different paths

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I attempt to have unique element names throughout the imported JSON file, but sometimes I will have hierarchical structure where element name is same but element are in different locations within same map.

I get wanted result but am wondering if there are better ways of querying a map to find nodes with same element names but with specific location.

The queries does not need to be in same template or "for-each". The queries can be triggered separately.

**Data:**

```
<data>
{
  "store1": {
    "pencils": 2
  },
  "store2": {
    "pencils": 5
  }
}
</data>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:transform version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
  exclude-result-prefixes="fn array map"
  expand-text="yes"
>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <!-- Parse JSON to XML -->

  <xsl:template match="data">
      <store>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)/*"/>
      </store>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[@key='store1']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="*[@key='pencils']"></xsl:copy-of>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[@key='store2']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="*[@key='pencils']"></xsl:copy-of>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<store xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <number xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" key="pencils">2</number>
   <number xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" key="pencils">5</number>
</store>
```

Comment: Hard to find criteria as to what is better, if all you want are those two numbers then replace `<xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)/*"/>` with `<xsl:copy-of select="json-to-xml(.)//*:number[@key = 'pencils']"/>`. Or keep your apply-templates but materialize the numbers with `<xsl:template match="*:number[@key = 'penicls']"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:template>`. Or fusion the two matches you have to `match="*[@key = ('store1', 'store2')]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?:

```
<xsl:template match="*[*[@key='pencils']]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="*[@key='pencils']"/>
</xsl:template>
```